# iOS delay touchUpInside button event

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation

I have some custom animations in my UIButton subclass. I override some inner methods for starting and ending animation

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    //there is my start animation
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    //there is my end animation
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    //there is my end animation
}
```

There is almost all good. All my buttons make some actions on event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. And there is my problem. Methods `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` are called only after my app handle `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event. So animations in button looks not so nice like I want.

So question is: can I delay `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event on some ms and firstly handle `touchesEnded` method of my button for smooth animation?